# background of custom icon in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

i am setting custom icon but its showing some white background rather then my transparent icon

here is may code that i have tried , i am using app compact actionbar

```
        this.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.home_actionbar);
        this.getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

and here is the screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a file in drawable folder. Name it "action_bar_icon_clicked", then paste this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/dark_grey" />
     <item android:drawable="@color/dark_grey"/>
</selector>
```

Then, in the style file, at the app theme add this line:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_bar_icon_clicked</item>
  </style>
```